# Issues with counting records in secondary table based on complex criteria

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need to be able to count the number of records in a secondary table `tblOptyRecordsHistorical` which are related to the main table `tblOptyRecordsCurrent`.

The tables are exactly the same, the main contains the current 'daily snapshot', the secondary table contains previous daily snapshots.

I have a number of flags which use the following basic syntax:

```
(SELECT COUNT(OpportunityRecordID) AS Expr1
FROM dbo.tblOptyRecordsHistorical AS hist
WHERE (OpportunityGlobalCRMId = curr.OpportunityGlobalCRMId)) 
AS prevEntries,
```

This works fine. But one flag, I need to count the number of records in the historical table, but the logic is more complicated and depends on values from the main table:

```
SELECT OpportunityGlobalCRMId, 
(SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN curr.PartnerGlobalCRMID IS NULL THEN CASE WHEN
hist.IgnoreOpportunity != 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ELSE CASE 
WHEN curr.CustomerAccountID IS NULL THEN CASE WHEN hist.IgnoreOpportunity = 1 AND 
hist.PartnerGlobalCRMID = curr.PartnerGlobalCRMID THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ELSE CASE WHEN
hist.IgnoreOpportunity = 1 AND CONVERT(varchar, hist.CustomerAccountID) + 
hist.PartnerGlobalCRMID = CONVERT(varchar, curr.CustomerAccountID) + 
curr.PartnerGlobalCRMID AND hist.OpptyIncentiveCreatedDate = 
curr.OpptyIncentiveCreatedDate THEN 1 ELSE 0 END END END) AS Expr1 FROM 
dbo.tblOptyRecordsHistorical AS hist WHERE (OpportunityGlobalCRMId = 
curr.OpportunityGlobalCRMId)) AS prevIgnored
FROM dbo.tblOptyRecordsCurrent AS curr
```

I've omitted the other flags and fields except for the initial `OpportunityGlobalCRMID`.  This results in the following error: `Multiple columns are specified in an aggregated expression containing an outer reference.  If an expression is being aggregated contains an outer reference, then that outer reference must be the only column referenced in the expression.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL Server does not like mixing of inner (`hist` table) and outer (`curr` table) in a aggregate subquery expression. Some explanation is available [here](http://sqlmag.com/blog/aggregates-outer-reference).

The proposed solutuon is to re-include the outer table in the sub-query, joining on it's key, in order to make all references inner. In your case, that would mean putting the `tblOptyRecordsCurrent` table inside the subquery, like this:

```
SELECT OpportunityGlobalCRMId, 
    (SELECT SUM(CASE 
                WHEN curr2.PartnerGlobalCRMID IS NULL 
                THEN CASE WHEN hist.IgnoreOpportunity != 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END 
                ELSE CASE 
                        WHEN curr2.CustomerAccountID IS NULL 
                        THEN CASE 
                            WHEN hist.IgnoreOpportunity = 1 AND hist.PartnerGlobalCRMID = curr2.PartnerGlobalCRMID THEN 1 ELSE 0 END 
                        ELSE CASE 
                            WHEN hist.IgnoreOpportunity = 1 
                                AND CONVERT(varchar, hist.CustomerAccountID) + hist.PartnerGlobalCRMID 
                                    = CONVERT(varchar, curr2.CustomerAccountID) + curr2.PartnerGlobalCRMID 
                                AND hist.OpptyIncentiveCreatedDate = curr2.OpptyIncentiveCreatedDate 
                            THEN 1 
                            ELSE 0 
                            END 
                    END 
            END) AS Expr1 
    FROM dbo.tblOptyRecordsHistorical AS hist 
        inner join dbo.tblOptyRecordsCurrent AS curr2 on curr2.OpportunityGlobalCRMId = hist.OpportunityGlobalCRMId
    WHERE curr2.OpportunityGlobalCRMId = curr.OpportunityGlobalCRMId) AS prevIgnored
FROM dbo.tblOptyRecordsCurrent AS curr
```

Haven't tested the code however.